# keyframes animations not returning to first point or repeating

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm trying to use a keyframe that will not return to first position, I mean if I have a transition from left to right, to stay right not return to the left side.

**Code**

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to the div.

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: example;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
    0%   {background-color:red; left:0px; top:0px;}
    100% {background-color:yellow; left:200px; top:0px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add 'animation-iteration-count: 1' it will work single time or if you want to take it in the loop then can try 'animation-iteration-count: infinite' into the div.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1; /*value can be infinite if you want to it in loop */
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50%{
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}


/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  50%{
    background-color: yellow;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: red;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```